# Display driver not correct updating older laptop to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I'm working on extending the life of an older laptop (late 2010-ish) by maxing out the RAM, upgrading to an SSD, and updating from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

I added the new hardware and installed Windows on the laptop, and everything works well except the graphics driver. My only choices for screen resolution are `1024x768` and `800x600`. I should be able to do `1366x768`.

Looking in the device manager, I see **two** entries for `Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)`. As part of my troubleshooting, I swapped the old Windows 7 disk back in and checked the driver there, and `Mobile Intel 4 Series Express` is the correct device. The only difference I see is two instances listed in device manager, rather than just one.

[image: Device manager]

Additionally, if I choose `Advanced Display Settings` when I go to try to change the resolution, I can see more information about the adapter and the monitor. This screen says the computer is using the `Microsoft Basic Display Driver`, in contradiction of what was shown by the device manager.

[image: Advanced Display Settings]

How can I get Windows to use the correct display driver? Or, where can I find a driver for this graphics chip that will work with Windows 10x64? (I'd even attempt to install a Windows 8 version for that device if I can find it). Or, if all else fails, how can I get the MS Basic Display driver to use the full 1366x768 resolution for the screen on this computer?

Comment: Your best chance at finding drivers for Windows 10 x64 would be the laptop manufacture's website. As far as the basic display adapter, I believe it only has certain resolutions. In the times I've had to use it, it never supported my max resolution. It's only meant for temporary use until you install the integrated or dedicated graphics drivers. If there are no drivers listed for Windows 10 on the manufactures site, try the latest drivers are listed for Windows 8 or 8.1.

Comment: That much I understand... but it's weird that it seems I **did** detect and install the correct driver. It only shows Basic Display Driver if I check in Advanced Settings. Device Manager does show the driver.

Comment: Oh, so you got those drivers from the manufacture website or were they automatically detected and installed by Windows/device manager?

Comment: I've done both. Had MS/WDDM driver when I wrote the post, currently running Intel version 8.15.10.2413, with same issues (2 instances in DM, Basic in Advanced, only crappy resolutions available). This is an older laptop that's no longer listed on the laptop vendor's site.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I was able to find the Intel drivers for your product.  However, Windows 10 compatible drivers, do not exist.  WDDM 1.1 was Windows 7.  Just because drivers were installed does not mean, they are compatible with Windows 10, especially if you are using WDDM 1.1.  At a minimum, you would have to be using WDDM 2.x to accomplish your goal, which is not possible with Intel's display drivers, designed only to work with Windows 7 and Windows Vista.  The fact you are using 8.15.10.2413 indicates the drivers you have installed are very old.

Comment: There may be no compatible drivers for that chipset and Windows 10, only XP thru Vista, I would try the last one provided for Vista, click the "show more" icon to see all of them....https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81507

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get the MS Basic Display driver to use the full 1366x768
>   resolution for the screen on this computer?

This will not be possible.

> How can I get, Windows to use, the correct display driver?  Where can I find a driver for this graphics chip that will work with Windows 10 64-bit?

If a Windows 10 compatible driver exists for Windows 10 it would be found on Intel's website.

> Looking in the device manager, I see two entries for Mobile Intel(R) 4
>   Series Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1).

If you had the correct driver installed, Windows 10 April 2018 Update, would be using WDDM 2.4.  The fact Windows 10 is attempting to use WDDM 1.1 indicates you don't have Intel's display drivers installed.  WDDM 1.1 was only used by Windows 7.

Windows 10 compatible drivers do not exist for your product.  Intel only released support Windows Vista an Windows 7 compatible drivers for your product.

> This software driver package will install the Intel® HD Graphics
>   driver for the Intel® Core™ Processors with Intel® HD Graphics. These
>   drivers will not function with any other product. View the README file
>   for installation information and the RELEASE NOTES for driver version
>   details. This driver package contains version 15.22.58.64.2993
>   (8.15.10.2993) for Windows 7* 64-bit and Windows Vista* 64-bit.

[Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator Driver, Windows 7* 64, Windows Vista* 64](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22521/Intel-Graphics-Media-Accelerator-Driver-Windows-7-64-Windows-Vista-64-exe-)